# Synchronous Dispatch Doesn't Work?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, grand-central-dispatch

Maybe I'm not understanding the concept but shouldn't this second piece of code wait before the first one is done?

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> () in
    // do some task
    var myRef = self.userRef.childByAppendingPath(self.userRef.authData.uid)
    myRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        println("WE ARE IN HERE")
        firstName = snapshot.value["firstName"] as String!
        lastName = snapshot.value["lastName"] as String!
    })
});

dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> () in
    // do some task
    var standbyData = [
        "firstName":firstName,
        "lastName":lastName,
        "duration":self.helpDurationLabel.text!,
        "radius":self.helpRadiusLabel.text!,
        "categories": categories,
        "time_stamp":self.date.timeIntervalSince1970
    ]
    println("WE ARE OUT HERE")
    var standbyUserRef = self.standbyRef.childByAppendingPath(self.userRef.authData.uid)
    standbyUserRef.updateChildValues(standbyData)
});
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Output is:

```
"WE ARE OUT HERE"
"WE ARE IN HERE"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does wait until the first finishes execution. Where the system is confusing you is with your usage of `myRef.observeSingleEventOfType(, withBlock:`

99% of APIs that request an execution block will push their operations onto a separate thread and then execute the block upon completion. The `observeSingleEventOfType` is probably returning shortly after scheduling its execution to an operation queue, causing your `dispatch_sync` to exit before the block is executed.

Instead, you're probably looking for something more like this:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> () in
    // do some task
    var myRef = self.userRef.childByAppendingPath(self.userRef.authData.uid)
    myRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        println("WE ARE IN HERE")
        firstName = snapshot.value["firstName"] as String!
        lastName = snapshot.value["lastName"] as String!

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> () in
            // do some task
            var standbyData = [
                "firstName":firstName,
                "lastName":lastName,
                "duration":self.helpDurationLabel.text!,
                "radius":self.helpRadiusLabel.text!,
                "categories": categories,
                "time_stamp":self.date.timeIntervalSince1970
            ]
            println("WE ARE OUT HERE")
            var standbyUserRef = self.standbyRef.childByAppendingPath(self.userRef.authData.uid)
            standbyUserRef.updateChildValues(standbyData)
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: If myRef.observeSingleEventOfType() executes and returns, how does the second dispatch_sync inside know to wait? Also, will dispatching to global queue freeze my UI?

Comment: Also, thank you for the answer, this works. Trying to get some clarification now.

Comment: The second `dispatch_sync` in the code example that I posted above is executing *inside* the block that you pass to `observeSingleEventOfType`.

Comment: Ah, thank you that makes sense. Will this freeze any UI interaction with the user? And if so, is the answer below a way of getting around that?

Comment: If you are acting on the main thread (`dispatch_get_main_queue()`), then you could be halting UI interaction. Because you are not doing this, it will not freeze anything. Be careful to only update UI elements on the main queue, though. As far as the other answer goes, it does not address the issue that you are seeing -- the block will still be executed after your second dispatch for the reasons I stated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

dispatch_get_global_queue is used to run task in background concurrently means anyone task can run first . As you are printing "we are in" and "we are out" means anyone can run first.
Instead of it I would recommend to run task serially rather than concurrently
dispatch_queue_create is used to run task serially.
I hope following code will help to fix this issue.

```
var backgroundQueue:dispatch_queue_t =  dispatch_queue_create("SerialQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

        dispatch_sync(backgroundQueue, { () -> () in
            // do some task
            var myRef = self.userRef.childByAppendingPath(self.userRef.authData.uid)
            myRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
                println("WE ARE IN HERE")
                firstName = snapshot.value["firstName"] as String!
                lastName = snapshot.value["lastName"] as String!
            })
        });

        dispatch_sync(backgroundQueue, { () -> () in
            // do some task
            var standbyData = [
                "firstName":firstName,
                "lastName":lastName,
                "duration":self.helpDurationLabel.text!,
                "radius":self.helpRadiusLabel.text!,
                "categories": categories,
                "time_stamp":self.date.timeIntervalSince1970
            ]
            println("WE ARE OUT HERE")
            var standbyUserRef = self.standbyRef.childByAppendingPath(self.userRef.authData.uid)
            standbyUserRef.updateChildValues(standbyData)
        });
```